# pandas.read_csv() does not load special characters

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm loading a dataset from a .csv file that includes special characters such as €, ă or ș.

Normally they should load ok with UTF-8 encoding, but when displaying them in a jupyter notebook all these characters are not rendered properly.

example: **25 000 €** is seen as [image]

code I use to load the .csv file:

```py
inter_df = pd.read_csv(
            f,
            header=0,
            sep='|',
            encoding='utf-8',
            engine='python',
            error_bad_lines=False
        )
```

Can anybody suggest a solution on how to handle these special characters?

Comment: Probably file encoding is wrong. Can you check it?

Comment: @mxmt - file encoding is UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is Windows-1252 encoding interpreting a UTF-8 character.€ in UTF-8 is E282AC, which corresponding to Windows-1252 á ‚ ¬. I don't think it's pandas problem since your file is correctly decoded using utf-8 decoder or there should be an error. Since you mentioned you load it in jupyter notebook, the displayed encoding is decided by your browser. Usually, jupyter will send a `Content-Type` header and specify the charset is UTF-8. However if jupyter is too old or browser is too old they may not use this attribute (As far as I know IE 11 will ignore this if you don't set IE encoding settings to auto). Thus the browser will try to interpret these characters in Windows-1252 encoding.

Comment: you are correct - I recently started using jupyter lab instead of jupyter notebook. Looks like the version of jupyter lab I was using was 1.2.3. I've updated to 2.2.9 and it solved the problem. Many thanks for you help!